# How to turn console outputted characters into a string; c++

Tags: c++, string, text, character, line

I would like to take a series of characters and assign them to a string variable.

Here an excerpt of my C++ code, followed by a further description of the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main () {

   string line = "MJQQT BTWQI";

   int shift = 5;
   int oldShift = 5;
   int count = 0;

   cout << "Enter your string to shift: ";
   getline(cin,line);
   cout << "Enter your shift number: ";
   cin >> shift;
   oldShift = shift;

   while(count < line.length())
   {


        if(line[count] != ' '){

                if((line[count]-shift) < 'A')
                    shift -= 26;


            line[count] = line[count] - shift;
            shift = oldShift;
            cout << line[count];

        } else{ line[count] = ' ';
            cout << line[count];
        }
    count++;
   }




   return 0;
}
```

The output looks like:

> Enter your string to shift: HELLO
>
> Enter your shift value: 5
>
> CZGGJ

I want to know how to assign the individual characters that are printed out one at a time in this loop to a new string. For example it the desired string would be

> newString = "CZGGJ"

Answer (score 0):

First, declare a string, i.e. `string stringOfChars;`. Once you have done so, wherever you write `cout << line[count];`, write `stringOfChars = stringOfChars + line[count];` underneath it.

Answer (score 0):

Declare something like

```
std::string newString = "";
```

Then after or before the cout statement, write

```
newString = newString + line[count];
```